# Had been or have been

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

I’m aware that this question has been asked a thousand of times already, but this time I really haven’t found any answer to my question.

Is it:

We all ***had been*** a child once.

Or

We all ***have been*** a child once.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Both are possible depending on the context. Btw, the "all" should come after the auxiliary verb: "We have/had all been a child once".

Comment: Consider using **We were all children  once**

Comment: @BillJ I mean the context was that I was talking to my friend about when we were kids, then I didn’t know which one to choose. We’re not children anymore so using had been makes more right ? I don’t know…

Comment: In that case, only the second one is possible. Note that we might more naturally say "We were all children once".

Comment: If we are all dead, then past perfect could be correct.

Comment: @gotube: I don't think the Past Perfect / Present Perfect choice has any particular connection to whether we're all dead or not "at time of utterance" (whatever *that* means, if we're all dead! :) All that matters is *the current "narrative reference time"* (if preceding / following text is centered around some point in *past* time, use Past Perfect; otherwise use Present Perfect). see [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=We+all+had+been%2CWe+had+all+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are very awkward.
You're separating the structures and masking the issue a little, but you don't have agreement on number, for starters.

Simplify it, bring it to simple present tense and you will see why.

> We all are a child.

hmm… no. Try

> We all are children.

Better.
So, let's take it back into past tense. The simplest version is the one most likely to be used in common speech.

> We all were children once.

If we build from that, then we *could* use

> We all have been children once, or
> We all had been children once.

Both are now acceptable, but feel a little 'stiff'. Each could have its place, but you'd have to choose carefully. Stick with the simplest version.

The choice between 'all were' or 'were all' is stylistic. 'All were' still feels a little archaic, but actually is a form I use a lot. (I'm old ;)